# populating table in stored procedure, mysql

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

Can anyone shed light on why this will not loop through the function and populate the temp table? Ive tried a number of things and at best can only get the first value to populate. I'm trying to take a value and a ":" separated string (queried in this procedure) to populate a table so I can reference it in a larger query. The function SPLIT_STR works great on its own but I cant seem to increment value "a" so that it separates ALL values per field per value.

```
BEGIN

 DECLARE platform_val VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE productName_val VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
 DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 1;


    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT
    ProductName,
    ProductPlatforms
    FROM Feed
    limit 10;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

 OPEN cur1;

 select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

  the_loop: LOOP

FETCH  cur1
INTO   productName_val,
       platform_val;

SET str = platform_val;
WHILE a< num_rows DO
SET str=SPLIT_STR(str,":",a);
    insert into temp values (productName_val, str);
    SET a=a+1;
END WHILE;



END LOOP the_loop;

END
```

Comment: do you have an example row and expected output of that row cause what you've done looks awfully complicated

Comment: it would be "productName", "Android::BlackBerry::iPhone::J2ME::PalmOS::Symbian::Windows Mobile::Beos::Dos::Fedora::FreeBSD::Linux::MacOS::OpenBSD::Windows 2000::Windows 7::Windows 9x::Windows NT::Windows Vista::Windows XP::Novell NetWare::Solaris::Unix::Windows Server 2003::Windows Server 2008" and I would want the ProductName repeated row by row with each "::" separated value like Product Name, Windows NT

Comment: so each row has each productName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the idea I came up with

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `col2lines`()
BEGIN
    declare v_platform,v_productName,v_platformAll varchar(255) default null;
    declare v_finished int default 0;

    declare curs cursor for select ProductName,ProductPlatforms from Feed limit 10;
    declare continue handler for not found set v_finished = 1;

    drop temporary table if exists temp_table;
    create temporary table temp_table (
        productName varchar(255),
        platform varchar(255)
    );

    open curs;

    parent: LOOP
        fetch curs into v_productName, v_platformAll;

        if (v_finished = 1) then LEAVE parent; end if;

        child: LOOP
            set v_platform = substring_index(v_platformAll, '::', 1);
            set @strlen = char_length(v_platform);
            if (@strlen > 0) then
                insert into temp_table values (v_productName, v_platform);
                set v_platformAll = substr(v_platformAll, @strlen + 3);
                iterate child;
            end if;
            LEAVE child;
        END LOOP child;

        iterate parent;
    END LOOP parent;

    close curs;

    select * from temp_table;
END
```

Comment: i added     declare v_platformAll varchar(255) default null;
            declare v_productName varchar(255) default null;         since it was barking about that, and also it did not like select temp_table. After removing it, i ran it and no table was created or populated. :/

Comment: ow yes, i forgot to declare those. not sure why it didnt like select temp_table....

Comment: select * from temp_table shows correct output. now to get it to put it into the table.

Comment: this worked great I really appreciate your help. You are a gentleman(person?) and a scholar.

Comment: i think you can remove the last `LEAVE parent` out... and thanks :)